# SQL: List of users that meet a condition N times

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data that looks something like:

```
Date        UserID    Visits
2012-01-01  2         5
...
```

I would like to output a list of users who have > x visits on at least y dates (e.g., the users who have >5 visits for at least 3 dates from January 3 to January 10).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUB.UserId, COUNT(*) FROM (
     SELECT VL.UserId FROM VisitLog VL
        WHERE VL.Visits > 5
              AND VL.Date BETWEEN '2014-01-03' AND '2014-01-10') SUB
   GROUP BY SUB.UserId
   HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```

The sub query returns all rows where the number of `Visits > 5` between your sample date range.
The results of this are then counted to return only users where this condition has been matched at least 3 times.

You don't give much information but if you have multiple records per date per user then use this query (exactly the same principal, just an inner grouping to sum by user and date):

```
SELECT SUB.UserId, COUNT(*) FROM (
     SELECT VL.UserId, VL.Date FROM VisitLog VL
            WHERE VL.Date BETWEEN '2014-01-03' AND '2014-01-10'
            GROUP BY VL.UserId, VL.Date 
            HAVING SUM(VL.Visits) > 5) SUB
   GROUP BY SUB.UserId
   HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```

Comment: you are providing a better design on the table. The first SQL perfectly answered the question. But I like the 2nd one. The first one assumes the Date and UserId contribute to primary key, while your 2nd solution assumes there is no primary key ---- whenever a user visit, just insert one row, brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select UserID,SUM(Visits) from TableOfData
where Date>@HereTheDate
group by UserID
having SUM(Visits)>5
```

Comment: This does not work on two points, firstly there is no date *range* and secondly you are not counting the occurrences of more than 5 visits

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from users
where id in (
    select UserID
    from userVisits
    where date between '2014-01-03' and '2014-01-10'
    and visits >= 5
    group by userid
    having count(*) >= 3)
```